# javascript not working once I remove it from the HTML and put it in its own file

Tags: javascript, external

So my javascript loads perfectly in the head tag but whilst it is in a external file it does not load.
I have loaded properly the javascript and jquery also setup the external file correctly. 
Here is the external javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)

    $('#imageResults').load("pageProcess/fresh_page_process.php", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

    $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll

        //if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
        var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    // calculate the percentage the user has scrolled down the page
    var scrollPercent = (scrollAmount / documentHeight) * 100;

    if(scrollPercent > 70) {
        // run a function called doSomething
       loadContent();
    }

    function loadContent()



        {

            if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
            {
                loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                $.post('pageProcess/fresh_page_process.php',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                    $("#imageResults").append(data); //append received data into the element

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    track_load++; //loaded group increment
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the index file

```
<head>
<title>AchieveNothing  - Last chance to socialize</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/style.css">

<?php
include("server_config/config.php");
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate");
$total_records = $results->fetchColumn(); 
#echo $get_total_rows;  

//break total records into pages
$total_groups = ceil($total_records/$item_per_group);

?>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="category">

Fresh
<?php
echo "<br/>";
echo "Total pages: " .$total_groups. "<br/>";
?>
<a href="imageUpload/file_Uploader.php">Upload</a>
</div>

<div id="total_warp">
<div id="imageResults">
</div>
</div>


<div class="animation_image" style="display:none" align="center"><img src="server_config/serverImages/ajax-loader.gif" width="50" height="50"></div>

</body>
```

So basically my javascript works fine if its written on the index however if i put it separate the javascript wont load.

Comment: Try to remove type="text/javascript" from: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script> I had the same problem and this fixed it

Comment: That has not fixed anything any other ideas?

Comment: Well I dont really see any mistake in your code. It seems right

Comment: Try passing an absolute path to the script's `src`. Make sure you can access the javascript in your browser, then replace the `src` attribute with the FULL address that you've used in the browser.

Comment: Formatting is pretty easy. Insert your code, select all of it and click the `{}` button. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You are sure your code is on a web or local server right? PHP only runs there... Also your `total_groups` variable is a non-encapsulated PHP string. On-page PHP will transform it before JS kicks in. However, put in your JS, it will not work like that.  You can't directly pass a PHP string to a JS file and expect it to work. You should put `<?php echo $total_groups; ?>;` in some container, then retrieve the value with JS.

Comment: My code is on a local server, as i have said the code runs perfectly if the javascript is in the head of the index.php, however if i try to run the javascript from the external source in the index.php nothing loads up.

Comment: It also seems that my javascript also uses php inside the script function. I know for sure that javascript cannot support php. So does that mean that i cannot call the javascript from external source??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, the problem is that you have a `PHP` statement in your Javascript file, which did get parsed in your PHP file, but will not be parsed in the external JS file.

```
var total_groups = <?php echo $total_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)
```

This produces a Javascript error. It is not a string value, and even if it would be, nothing would happen, because this PHP runs on the server, before the page is loaded.

You need to get the PHP property on your HTML file first:

```
<input type="hidden" id="total-groups-val" value="<?php echo $total_groups; ?>">
```

Then you can retrieve it with JS like so:

```
var total_groups = document.getElementById('total-groups-val').value;
```

Comment: Hey, I managed to fix it. Thank you i owne you so much. I knew the problem was with that variable but i did not know how to fix it. Thank you once again, Also is there optimal place where to put the input type hidden inside document??

Comment: Not really, though to easily find it you might want to put it at the start/ end of the `body` tag.

Comment: @user3741224 The optimal place is before `</body>` because it allows the browser to load and parse the HTML with more immediacy. As soon as the browser hits `<script>` the parser stops parsing HTML that follows until the script is loaded.

Comment: @user3741224 please mark this answer as correct. It is a good answer.